# How to change syntax color in vim?

Tags: 16.04, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But vim is not showing the proper syntax colors and also the mode in which you are like insert mode. So can anyone help me how to solve the issue?

Comment: are you talking about vim?

Comment: yes its vim...in this vi editor the mode and different syntax colour not showing

Comment: how to solve ...plzzz reply asap

Comment: Ubuntu comes with vim-tiny or something. You have to run `sudo apt install vim` to get a full-featured vim

Answer (score 11):

For syntax highlighting in vim, first install vim

```
sudo apt install vim
```

then run

```
$ cd /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors
/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors$ ls
```

From its output:

```
blue.vim      desert.vim    koehler.vim  peachpuff.vim  slate.vim
darkblue.vim  elflord.vim   morning.vim  README.txt     torte.vim
default.vim   evening.vim   murphy.vim   ron.vim        zellner.vim
delek.vim     industry.vim  pablo.vim    shine.vim
```

Modify file `~/.vimrc`

`vi ~/.vimrc` or `gedit ~/.vimrc`
and edit

```
colorscheme koehler
```

or any you like.

Comment: @Surajkumar If it helpful to you then please [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote) and accept it. Read [Tour Page](https://askubuntu.com/tour)